# Simple Android Mobile Java App Example using Android Actions / Assistant

Tags: actions-on-google

Please can anyone point me to Simple Android Java App Example using Android Actions / Assistant (for mobile) ? I have a java android mobile app, which I would like to control from Google Assistant/Home (for example Google change background colour to yellow).

I have tried several days to find some simple example, but all what I get is Dialogflow implementation with firebase (node.js) or code for non-mobile devices (for example raspberry pi). I would imagine that Android Mobile should have pretty close / easy integration to Google Actions.

Comment: were you able to implement your use-case?